# Asp.net core how to get Id from url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Hay, I'm creating a website like wikipedia and I need to get the id from url to show correct view. This is my route config:

```
private void ConfigureRoutes(IRouteBuilder routeBuilder)
{
    routeBuilder.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
}
```

The id will be name of the view that controller will return.

Comment: Are you asking how to get a parameter from a URL or how to return a different view from a controller? Or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where are you getting stuck? The default mapping that Visual Studio sets up for you supports this already. Just add an `id` parameter to your controller method and use it to look up your content.

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    if (id != null)
    {
        // Lookup topic from id
    }
}
```